# Where to store .txt and .pdf in Android?

Tags: android, android-assets

In my application, I need to store `.txt` and `.pdf` so that I can open them in the app. Which folder would be the best place for these files to reside. I've considered values, but I'm guessing the assets folder? When I need to call these files from said folder, how would I call it `(R.assets.myfile.txt)`?

I just want to make sure I put them in the right place, as eclipse doesn't give an error when they reside elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bundle them in the app, put them in `assets/` and use the `AssetManager` to read them from the app.

Comment: Yeah, That is a good choice for storing the files and using in the app. Cheers!.